# Cropping Image inside promises using canvas not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to crop multiple images using canvas and I want to run some other function after I'm done with cropping all the images.

This is my promise function to crop images

```
const checkImage = url => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const workingURL = url;
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 200;
    canvas.height = 200;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  
    img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
    img.onload = function(){
      var w = img.width;
      var h = img.height;

      var rw = 200;
      var rh = 200;

      if (w > h) {
        var ar = (w / h).toFixed(2);
        var dar = (200/h);
        rw = Math.floor(w * dar);
      } else if (h > w) {
        var ar = (h / w).toFixed(2);
        var dar = (200/w);
        rh = Math.floor(h * dar);
      }

      var sx = 200 / 2 - rw / 2;
      var sy = 200 / 2 - rh / 2;
      console.log(sx, sy, rw, rh);
      console.log(img);
      ctx.drawImage(img,sx,sy, rw , rh);
      var s = canvas.toDataURL();
      console.log('done cropping ', url, s);
      resolve({url: workingURL, res: s});
    }
    img.onerror = (err) => {
      console.log('onload error ',err);
      resolve({url: workingURL, res: false});
    };
    img.src = url;
  });
}
```

now I have couple of images need to be called, so I'm calling promise with each image

```
cropImageForGIFFn = () => {
  const needCropImgs = [
    {
      "src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tech-turing/event-images/ydgPwb28ThtgeATC8/img-Hrc7otKvJZTg6D5Rp.png",
    },
    {
      "src": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tech-turing/event-images/ydgPwb28ThtgeATC8/img-ZAnRMDHfAGz2Xe9oX.png",
    },
  ];
  const needCropImgsLen = needCropImgs.length;
  let resolvedPromises = 0;

  needCropImgs.forEach(function (imgInfo) {      
    checkImage(imgInfo.src).then((info) => {
      console.log('promise resolved');
      console.log(info);

      resolvedPromises += 1;
      if (resolvedPromises === 1) {
        document.getElementById('img1').src = info.res;
      }

       if (resolvedPromises === 2) {
        document.getElementById('img2').src = info.res;
      }
      console.log({resolvedPromises});
      if (resolvedPromises >= needCropImgsLen) {
        console.log('all are resolved');
      }
    });
  });
};
```

I'm checking all promises are resolved or not and then calling some other function.

If I send multiple images to my promises function, first image is coming as transparent if I send only one image then everything working fine.

If I comment any of the images then cropping works fine.

I created Codepen here https://codepen.io/sasikanth1/pen/rQjxXL

try commenting one of the array values of `needCropImgs` then image will be displayed fine.

Comment: It seems like your main problem is the use of implicit globals, but it also seems that your codepen doesn't work because the images are failing to load due to a CORS error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typo**,
You forgot a `const` or `let` or `var` before `img` declaration.

```
   img = new Image();
 // ^- scope leak
```

This means your `img` variable in all the async callbacks will refer to the latest declared Image(). This could indeed lead to some transparent result if the last image didn't load before the other ones.

So simply add this keyword and you'll be fine.